# SQL Query in Hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, jdbc, dialect

I'm carrying out a SQL query which looks like:

```
SELECT thi.*
FROM track_history_items thi
JOIN artists art
  ON thi.artist_id = art.id
WHERE thi.type = TrackBroadcast
Group By art.name
ORDER thi.created_at DESC
```

This works fine when I run it directly on my database from MySql Workbench, but when I run in through Hibernate, I get a `No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1` error.

Anyone have any ideas what could be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably one or more of the columns in the query is not supported by the mysql dialect... try expanding the * and add one column at a time until you find the offending one.

Then it is just a matter of deciding whether you need that column or not.

Comment: one of my columns has type 'TEXT' - could this be the source of the problem..?

Comment: No, text should be fine. However, HOW that text field is mapped to your object could be causing a problem. If you posted your <table>.hbm.xml file we could shed more light on the problem.